# How to round number to nearest upper increment of 256 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Currently using `Math.round(number / 256) * 256`, but `320` is rounded to `256`.

Comment: `ceil` instead of `round`?

Comment: Really no reason to have this as yet another question on SO. Googling the question title reveals exactly the linked duplicate as the very first hit. (And even less of a reason to have 2 upvotes)

Comment: If you want to *increment*, does that mean you want 256 to result in 512, and 512 to result in 768, ...etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Math.ceil()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

```
Math.ceil(number / 256) * 256
```

Comment: I should really post a question titled "how do I round a number upwards to multiples of 123" and earn me some points... what is this rep farming...